# Checking if a list of strings can be chained

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, list

**Question**

Implement a function `bool chainable(vector<string> v)`, which takes a set of strings as parameters and returns `true` if they can be **chained**. Two strings can be chained if the first one ends with the same character the second starts with, e.g.:

```
ship->petal->lion->nick  = true;  (original input is list not LL)
ship->petal   axe->elf   = false;
```

**My Solution:**

My logic is that if its chainable there will only be one start and end that don't match. So I create a list of starts and a list of ends. like so.

```
starts:s,p,l,n
ends:  p,l,n,k
```

if I remove the common elements, the lists should contain at most one items. namely s and k. If so the list is chainable. If the list is cyclic, the final lists are empty.

But i think I am missing some cases here,

**EDIT:**
Okay clearly I had faults in my solution. Can we conclude the best algorithm for this ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that every string can be chained. What is the missing rule you are hiding from us?

Comment: ? see {ship,petal,axe,elf} how can  you make a single chain out o these? end letter of first should be start of second to make a chain.

Comment: ahh! it is about that the letters ending and starting must be the same. Thanks for clarification :)

Comment: How would you do this *without a computer*? This is very likely to be the simplest solution.

Comment: what if it is ship->petal->lion->link->ship->petal . Here start and end doesnt point to ship but its more of an circular loop With circle not being complete in last case ?

Comment: @Ritesh lion->link is not chainable

Comment: @Itsik thanks ...i read it wrong . What if its something like this ship->petal->lion->nerds->ship->petal ?

Comment: @Ritesh why are you including petal twice?

Comment: @Johnsyweb probably the simplest, but not the fastest

Comment: @Itsik for a circular case , in which starting and end element are not same . The case in which circle is not complete but say is just 1 and half or two and half

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is to check if a [Eulerian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) exists in the directed graph whose vertices are the letters occurring as first or last letter of at least one of the supplied words and whose edges are the supplied words (each word is the edge from its first letter to its last).

Some necessary conditions for the existence of Eulerian paths in such graphs:

1. The graph has to be connected.
2. All vertices with at most two exceptions have equally many incoming and outgoing edges. If exceptional vertices exist, there are exactly two, one of them has one more outgoing edge than incoming, the other has one more incoming edge than outgoing.

The necessity is easily seen: If a graph has Eulerian paths, any such path meets all vertices except the isolated vertices (neither outgoing nor incoming edges). By construction, there are no isolated vertices in the graph under consideration here. In a Eulerian path, every time a vertex is visited, except the start and end, one incoming edge and one outgoing edge is used, so each vertex with the possible exception of the starting and ending vertex has equally many incoming and outgoing edges. The starting vertex has one more outgoing edge than incoming and the ending vertex one more incoming edge than outgoing unless the Eulerian path is a cycle, in which case all vertices have equally many incoming and outgoing edges.

Now the important thing is that *these conditions are also sufficient*. One can prove that by induction on the number of edges.

That allows for a very efficient check:

- record all edges and vertices as obtained from the words
- use a union find structure/algorithm to count the connected components of the graph
- record `indegree - outdegree` for all vertices

If `number of components > 1` or there is (at least) one vertex with `|indegree - outdegree| > 1` or there are more than two vertices with `indegree != outdegree`, the words are not chainable, otherwise they are.

Comment: I think , this problem is more like finding a Hamiltonion path than a Euler path, since i can only use a word once, whereas in a euler path the vertices can be used more than once.

Comment: But in a Eulerian path you use every *edge* only once. The *words* are the *edges* in my model, the vertices are the letters (first/last letters of the words). So it's indeed Eulerian and not Hamiltonian in my model.

Comment: oh, yeah. apologies. btw, Can i find a solution to finding a eulerian path ? or a tutorial of sorts that gives me a basic understanding of the algorithm?

Comment: For finding a Eulerian path, [Hierholzer's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Hierholzer.27s_algorithm) is pretty efficient. You have to slightly modify it for directed graphs and/or the occurrence of two exceptional points with odd degree, but the basic principle holds. Concerning the sketched algorithm, [union find is explained here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), the other part should be obvious to implement; for the understanding, I don't know. It's pretty obvious with some knowledge of topology and homology, but without?

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I, personally, would prefer more about the reduction to Eulerian path and less about when an Eulerian path exists in a graph. 
That is, the interesting part about this problem is the reduction to Eulerian path.

Comment: @Chris I'd be happy to oblige, but I don't understand which points you'd like to have elaborated. Once you view the problem as a graph with the words as edges, it's clear that the question is whether you can form a path using each edge once, i.e. a Eulerian path (or trail) as I later learned. From then on, the problem is finding necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of such a path which can be checked as efficiently as possible. How to get the idea to view the words as edges and not as vertices as so many others have done, I don't know, it's what occurred naturally to me.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't that similar to the infamous [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

If you have `n` strings, you can construct a graph out of them, where each node corresponds to one string. You construct the edges the following way:

- If string (resp. node) `a` and `b` are chainable, you introduce an edge `a -> b` with weight `1`.
- For *all unchainable* strings (resp. nodes) `a` and `b`, you introduce an edge `a -> b` with weight `n`.

Then, all your strings are chainable (without repetition) if and only if you can find an optimal TSP route in the graph whose weight is less than `2n`.

**Note:** Your problem is actually simpler than TSP, since you always can transform string chaining into TSP, but not necessarily the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a case where your algorithm doesn't work:

```
ship
pass
lion
nail
```

Your start and end lists are both `s, p, l, n`, but you can't make a single chain (you get two chains - `ship->pass` and `lion->nail`).

A recursive search is probably going to be best - pick a starting word (1), and, for each word that can follow it (2), try to solve the smaller problem of creating a chain starting with (2) that contains all of the words except (1).

Comment: yes, you are right. thanks! 
I knew i was missing something, couldnt be that easy. ne workarounds you can think ?

Comment: You have an algorithm in m ind ?

Answer (score 3):

As phimuemue pointed out, this is a graph problem. You have a set of strings (vertices), with (directed) edges. Clearly, the graph must be [connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29) to be chainable -- this is easy to check. Unfortunately, the rules beyond this are a little unclear:

If strings may be used more than once, but links can't, then the problem is to find an [Eulerian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), which can be done efficiently. An Eulerian path uses each edge once, but may use vertices more than once.

```
// this can form a valid Eulerian path
yard
dog
god
glitter

yard -> dog -> god -> dog -> glitter
```

If the strings may not be used more than once, then the problem is to find a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). Since the Hamiltonian path problem is NP-complete, no exact efficient solution is known. Of course, for small *n*, efficiency isn't really important and a brute force solution will work fine.

*However*, things are not quite so simple, because the set of graphs that can occur as inputs to this problem are limited. For example, the following is a valid directed graph (in [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) notation) (*).

```
digraph G {
    alpha -> beta;
    beta -> gamma;
    gamma -> beta;
    gamma -> delta;
}
```

However, this graph cannot be constructed from strings using the rules of this puzzle: Since *alpha* and *gamma* both connect to *beta*, they must end with the same character (let's assume they end with 'x'), but *gamma* also connects to *delta*, so *delta* must also start with 'x'. But *delta* cannot start with 'x', because if it did, then there would be an edge `alpha -> delta`, which is not in the original graph.

Therefore, this is *not* quite the same as the Hamiltonian path problem, because the set of inputs is more restricted. It is possible that an efficient algorithm exists to solve the string chaining problem even if no efficient algorithm exists to solve the Hamiltonian path problem.

But... I don't know what that algorithm would be. Maybe someone else will come up with a real solution, but in the mean time I hope someone finds this answer interesting.

(*) It also happens to have a Hamiltonian path: `alpha -> beta -> gamma -> delta`, but that's irrelevant for what follows.

Comment: Considering my knowledge of graphs is new and sparse, i did not understand most of what you said. :). I am studying about graphs now. Will reply soon. But i do understand that this does sound like a graph problem.

Answer (score 2):

if you replace `petal` and `lion` with `pawn` and `label`, you still have:
`starts:s,p,l,n`
`ends:  p,l,n,k`

You're algorithm decides its chainable, but they aren't.
The problem is you are disconnecting the first and last letters of each word.

A recursive backtracking or dynamic programming algorithm should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

seperatedly check for "Is chainable" and is "cylcic"

if it's to be cyclic it must be chainable first. you could do something like this:

```
if (IsChainable)
{
  if (IsCyclic() { ... }
}
```

Note: That's the case if you check only the first and last element of the chain for "cylic".

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by a reduction to the Eulerian path problem by considering a digraph G with N(G) = Σ and E(G) = `a->e` for words `aWe`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple program to do this iteratively:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

bool isChained(vector<string> const& strngs)
{
    if (strngs.size() < 2) return false;      //- make sure we have at least two strings
    if (strngs.front().empty()) return false; //- make sure 1st string is not empty

    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 1; i < strngs.size(); ++i)
    {
        string const& head = strngs.at(i-1);
        string const& tail = strngs.at(i);
        if (tail.empty())  return false;
        if (head[head.size()-1] != tail[0])  return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string>  chained;
    chained.push_back("ship");
    chained.push_back("petal");
    chained.push_back("lion");
    chained.push_back("nick");

    vector<string>  notChained;
    notChained.push_back("ship");
    notChained.push_back("petal");
    notChained.push_back("axe");
    notChained.push_back("elf");

    std::cout << (isChained(chained) ? "true" : "false") << "\n";     //- prints 'true'
    std::cout << (isChained(notChained) ? "true" : "false") << "\n";  //- prints 'false'

    return 0;
}
```